# Create backdrop of Material Design in React Native

Tags: react-native, material-design, material-ui

I'm starting with a new project in `ReactNative` and I want to use Backdrop widget in this project.

Being a beginner I'm not having an idea of how to achieve this. Even I have searched for the Material components library like `react-native-material-ui` and `react-native-paper` for this, but unfortunately, this library doesn't have this component.

Desired screen :

[image]
[image]

Desired output video : 
[Backdrop Material UI](https://storage.googleapis.com/spec-host-backup/mio-components%2Fassets%2F1LQJoroTtDfEhF4ZQZY6GDTd_P-mduKTv%2Fbehavior-reveal.mp4)

I don't have any code or haven't tried anything, but searched for the component. Any Reference links are welcomed.

Comment: quick googling found me couple of libraries which can do what you need. Just search for `backdrop material design react native`

Comment: I guess this is what you want: [React Native Parallax Scroll View](https://github.com/i6mi6/react-native-parallax-scroll-view)

Comment: @MinhDao No not the parallax effect.

Comment: @HaykShakhbazyan Thanks for this man. I don't know why I was not getting these libs earlier. I'll try this out. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Well, I found a collection of RN libraries. You can take a look: [Awesome RN UI](https://github.com/madhavanmalolan/awesome-reactnative-ui)

Comment: I know this question is very old but maybe it still helps. Only library I know that implements Material Design Backdrop is NxMatBackdrop. Its written for Angular but maybe you can get some inspirations from it. [NxMatBackdrop](https://github.com/mifloma/ngx-mat-backdrop).